# Zabbix 3 - trigger add to item

Tags: php, zabbix

How to associate a trigger with a data item (item) via an API?
**[In the API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/host/create)** I do not see this.
In the documentation I can not find.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [trigger.create](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/trigger/create) api and to the [trigger object properties](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/trigger/object#trigger)